# TIdFtp in Delphi XE2 - connect method very slow

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy10

I'm using TIdFTP (Indy 10.2) in Delphi XE2; the method 'connect' (to create a connection...) is very slow; it takes 7 - 8 seconds to accomplish task.
I have tried with different configurations: Passive true or false, AutoLogin true or false, but more or less the same situation.
Is there any particular configuration to consider ?

Comment: Passive/Active does not apply to `Connect()`, only to `Get()` and `Put()`.

Comment: Ok, so which configuration / property can change Connect() behaviour ?

Comment: A lot, actually.  `Connect()` is influenced by half a dozen properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, 10.2 is a VERY OLD and OUTDATED version.  The current version is 10.6.  You should seriously consider upgrading.

Second, `Connect()` does a lot of work.  It always sends a `SYST` command at a minimum, but depending on the values of the following properties, it may send a lot of additional commands as well:

- UseHOST=True

  ```
  HOST
  ```
- AutoLogin=True

  ```
  AUTH 1-4 times (only if UseTLS is utUseRequireTLS or utUseExplicitTLS)
  XAUT (only if ProxySettings.ProxyType is fpcmNone)
  USER
  PASS
  ACCT
  OPEN (only if ProxySettings.ProxyType is fpcmOpen)
  EPSV ALL (only if EPSV is supported)
  SITE ZONE (only if SITE ZONE is supported)
  TYPE
  ```
- AutoIssueFEAT=True

  ```
  FEAT
  CLNT
  ```

So taking 7-8 seconds to complete is not unreasonable depending on how many commands it has to send and how much bandwidth you have available.  To make `Connect()` return as soon as possible, turn off all of the auto features, and then call `Login()` and `IssueFEAT()` manually when ready.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd verify if the issue is with Indy, have you tried connecting using a different ftp client (ftp at a command prompt, Filezilla, etc.), as it could be the server that is slow.  I remember an issue I had where the FTP server was attempting to do a reverse DNS lookup and stalling the connection.